# Match sentence groups based on digits before and after digits (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

**I am trying to pull data between /\n[\d-+]* / and /\n[\d-+]* / within my copy,**

I have gotten close, but my groups are generating empty "" copy.

Currently my Regex is:

```
/(?<!\n\d[-+]*)(.*?)(?=(\n\d|$))/sg
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/19OBCc/6)

An Example of my copy is below. It is a repeating pattern, but I'm getting confused as to how to make repeating groups work.

```
1 Failure, mutation may not be used again that day, roll on defects table.
2-11 Failure, mutation may not be used again that day.
12-13 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds one target for 1d3 rounds (save for half the duration), or optionally the mutant may generate a field of ambient light in a 40’ radius for 1 hour/CL.
14-17 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds one target for 1d6 rounds, save for half the duration.
18-19 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds up to 6 targets for 1d6 rounds, save for half the duration.
20-23 The mutant releases a series of strobing light pulses that blind and stun up to 6 targets for 1d6 rounds.
24-27 The mutant releases a cascade of dazzling light pulses that hypnotize up to 10 HD of targets for 1d8
rounds (save for half the duration) and places them in a highly suggestible state.
28-29 The mutant’s body releases a gigantic orb of pure photons that deals 6d6 damage to any targets in
a straight path to its final target, blinding anyone looking for 1d10 rounds (save for half damage
and duration).
30-31 The mutant fires a high energy beam of coherent light that permanently blinds one target and causes 8d6
of damage, save for temporary blindness (1d10 turns) and half damage.
32+ The mutant fires a high energy beam of coherent light that permanently blinds one target and causes 10d6
of damage, save for temporary blindness (1d10 days) and half damage; up to four additional adjacent
targets are blinded for 1d10 rounds.
```

The desired outcome would be (with the [0] representing each new group in the output array.)

```
[0] 1 Failure, mutation may not be used again that day, roll on defects table.
[1] 2-11 Failure, mutation may not be used again that day.
[2] 12-13 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds one target for 1d3 rounds (save for half the duration), or optionally the mutant may generate a field of ambient light in a 40’ radius for 1 hour/CL.
[3] 14-17 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds one target for 1d6 rounds, save for half the duration.
[4] 18-19 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds up to 6 targets for 1d6 rounds, save for half the duration.
[5] 20-23 The mutant releases a series of strobing light pulses that blind and stun up to 6 targets for 1d6 rounds.
[6] 24-27 The mutant releases a cascade of dazzling light pulses that hypnotize up to 10 HD of targets for 1d8
rounds (save for half the duration) and places them in a highly suggestible state.
[7] 28-29 The mutant’s body releases a gigantic orb of pure photons that deals 6d6 damage to any targets in
a straight path to its final target, blinding anyone looking for 1d10 rounds (save for half damage
and duration).
[8] 30-31 The mutant fires a high energy beam of coherent light that permanently blinds one target and causes 8d6
of damage, save for temporary blindness (1d10 turns) and half damage.
[9] 32+ The mutant fires a high energy beam of coherent light that permanently blinds one target and causes 10d6
of damage, save for temporary blindness (1d10 days) and half damage; up to four additional adjacent
targets are blinded for 1d10 rounds.
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I feel like I'm close and have learnt a lot, but have really come up against a wall. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each numbered item would all be contained within a single line, there is no reason why a simple string split should not work here, e.g.

```js
var input = `1 Failure, mutation may not be used again that day, roll on defects table.
2-11 Failure, mutation may not be used again that day.
12-13 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds one target for 1d3 rounds (save for half the duration), or optionally the mutant may generate a field of ambient light in a 40’ radius for 1 hour/CL.
14-17 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds one target for 1d6 rounds, save for half the duration.
18-19 The mutant releases a single flash of light that blinds up to 6 targets for 1d6 rounds, save for half the duration.
20-23 The mutant releases a series of strobing light pulses that blind and stun up to 6 targets for 1d6 rounds.
24-27 The mutant releases a cascade of dazzling light pulses that hypnotize up to 10 HD of targets for 1d8
rounds (save for half the duration) and places them in a highly suggestible state.
28-29 The mutant’s body releases a gigantic orb of pure photons that deals 6d6 damage to any targets in
a straight path to its final target, blinding anyone looking for 1d10 rounds (save for half damage
and duration).
30-31 The mutant fires a high energy beam of coherent light that permanently blinds one target and causes 8d6
of damage, save for temporary blindness (1d10 turns) and half damage.
32+ The mutant fires a high energy beam of coherent light that permanently blinds one target and causes 10d6
of damage, save for temporary blindness (1d10 days) and half damage; up to four additional adjacent
targets are blinded for 1d10 rounds.`;
console.log(input.split(/\r?\n/));
```

Assuming each item could have CR?LF inside it, you could make the above split more specific by using a positive lookahead:

```
console.log(input.split(/\r?\n(?=\s*\d+(?:\+|-\d+))/));
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately i cant control where the line breaks are (and will need to manicure them out) - However this gave me a idea to use Split instead of match,
tableData.split(/(?=(\n|\r)\d+ ?[-+]? ?\d* )/g); https://regex101.com/r/19OBCc/8

This works but id love to learn how to do it with Match. Either way, by finding the split point the regex becomes much easier!

Comment: Then edit your question and show us the real data.  My answer does, in fact, work for the sample data you did actually provide above.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Really appreciate your time to help me, i couldn't have got there without you- Will do!